# How do I identify fake referrals?

Tags: google-analytics

I went on Google Analytics and I am trying to find out whether I am getting fake or genuine referrals. I found it a bit weird because yesterday i got 17 sessions and I haven't been getting that high amount of sessions. I looked at sources and it said that 14 were referrals from simple-share-buttons.com. I had a look and this website isn't on any lists of fake referrals. I then went on landing pages and there were 14 that had landed on `192.168.1.58/` instead of `192.168.1.58/index.php`. I was wondering what I could do to find out whether these are genuine or fake.

Comment: Landing on / instead of /index.php or (any other variation) is not an issue. It is possible that one share results in several referrals. This is especially true since spiders will follow links on share and social media sites. So this does not surprise me. Social shares can drive traffic, however, much of it will be scraper bots that are following links and are not of any particular value. Some of these bots will help you since they are building real links to your site, though the value is often small. Sometimes these referrers are a user and so these shares have real value. Do not worry.

Comment: Anytime!! I am here every day and we have real experts here too.

Comment: If you would like to learn how to remove referrals like the one you mentioned, and other prevalent ones, like darodar, etc., you can read this blog: http://www.analyticsedge.com/2014/12/removing-referral-spam-google-analytics/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referrer spam typically has the following characteristics:

- The reported page title is fake ("Home Page" in the case of simple-share-buttons.com).
- The host name is fake or not set (while it should be one of the host names under which your Web site is reachable).
- Only `/` is targeted.

This answers your question about what you can do to determine whether referrals are genuine or fake.

If in addition you want to understand how this referrer spam is produced and what options you have to eliminate it, you may want to look at the following article I wrote some time ago:

http://veithen.github.io/2015/01/21/referrer-spam.html

In particular it explains the reason why referrer spam typically has the characteristics enumerated above.

Answer (score 1):

Besides landing on the home page `/`, Others signs of **Referrer Spam** are:

- `% Bounce Rate` of **0%** or **100%**
- `AVG session time` of **0s**
- `%new sessions` **0%**
- If you try to access the Referrer site(not recommendable) you will be redirected to another suspicious one (like darodar).

Any of this can point to a Referrer Spam, especially if it has 2 or more of this signs.

**Simple-share-buttons.com** is definitely a Referrer Spam is the same as the more known **buttons-for-website.com**

Comment: Bounce rate, average session time and %new sessions are not very reliable signals. For all three criteria you mention, I see counter-examples in the list of referrer spam I received over the last couple of days.